# How to make many TextView (post) in android studio like posts in Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, posts

I want to make an android application that allow user to write post(paragraphs) and post them in home interface where they write, so all users can see all posts. like the Facebook, each user can write many post and share it with others. In other word,I want one interface where users can write the post in text area and post it within same interface. any user login to this app can see his post and other users post.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXWFuar2Oq4

This video is slimier to what I am searching for, but it doesn't keep the previous post it just overwrite it.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

and you can add new textViews one after the other like a

[ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)